# Python importlib's analogue for imp.new_module()

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-importlib

PyCharm shows me that imp is deprecated so I wonder if there any analogue of imp.new_module for importlib.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Quoting from [documentation (Emphasis mine) -](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imp.html#imp.new_module)

> **imp.new_module(name)**
>
> Return a new empty module object called name. This object is not inserted in sys.modules.
>
> **Deprecated since version 3.4: Use [types.ModuleType](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.ModuleType) instead.**

Example -

```
>>> import types
>>> types.ModuleType('name')
<module 'name'>
```

To show how they are synonymous -

```
>>> import imp
>>> imp.new_module('name')
<module 'name'>
```

Comment: The only problem is, 3.6 documentation does recommend importlib's module_from_spec, but it seems impossible to use it in such a way. Modules constructed with types.ModuleType have None as `__spec__`, but `module_from_spec(None)` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

**Python** documentation suggests to us:

> Note Use **[importlib.util.module_from_spec()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.util.module_from_spec)** to create a new module if
> you wish to set the various import-controlled attributes.

**`importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)`** is preferred over using [`types.ModuleType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.ModuleType) to create a new module as **spec** is used to set as many import-controlled attributes on the module as possible.

To import a Python source file directly, we can use the following snippet:

```
import importlib.util
import sys


spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(module_name, file_path)
module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
sys.modules[module_name] = module
spec.loader.exec_module(module)
```

The example below, we can use to implement **lazy imports**:

```
import importlib.util
import sys

def lazy_import(name):
    spec = importlib.util.find_spec(name)
    loader = importlib.util.LazyLoader(spec.loader)
    spec.loader = loader
    module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    sys.modules[name] = module
    loader.exec_module(module)
    return module

>>> lazy_typing = lazy_import("typing")
>>> #lazy_typing is a real module object,
>>> #but it is not loaded in memory yet.
>>> lazy_typing.TYPE_CHECKING
False
```